# How do you set up foreign keys in an association table in Entity Framework 4.2

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Consider a table defined as:

```
    public class SkillInteraction
{
    // Primary Key
    [Key]
    public int SkillInteractionId { get; set; }

    // record type (offensive, defensive)
    public int SkillTypeId { get; set; }

    //foreign key to Skill table
    public int ParentSkillId { get; set; }

    //foreign key to Skill table
    [ForeignKey("ParentSkillId")]
    public virtual Skill ParentSkill { get; set; }

    //foreign key to Skill table
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    // list of skills associated with the parent skill
    [ForeignKey("SkillId")]
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }

    public decimal Ratio { get; set; }
}    
public class Skill
    {
        public int SkillId { get; set; }
        // record type (offensive, defensive)
        public int SkillTypeId { get; set; }
        public string SkillName { get; set; }
    }
```

Im fairly certain I need to map this relationship using the fluent syntax, just not sure how to go about it.  If i leave it as is, I will be an error with the foreign key causing cycles.

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'SkillInteraction_Skill' on table 'SkillInteractions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

so, how do i set up this relationship in EF 4.2 so that SQL server doesnt complain?

Answer (score 1):

u need to specify the relationship through the fluent api , by default ef will turn the `WillCascadeOnDelete` option ON , u need to turn it off. It cannot be done through annotations.

I wrote about this on my blog http://2guysfrommumbai.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/entity-framework-4-1-associations/ . Hope this helps.